# async functions in angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use async functions in angular 1.x.  It works except that you need force a digest update afterwards.  Is there a way to do this with decorators?  I had a look, but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: please show some code, what you have tried so for?

Comment: as for root case: async/await produce native `Promise`. Digest does not care about native promise resolved/rejected(as well as say XHR requests or timers). unfortunately have no idea how to make them friends in declarative way :(

Comment: @PankajParkar well if I throw in a $timeout after every async function completes, a digest cycle is updated.  My goal, is to let's say automate this for directives, controllers, etc.  $rootScope.apply also works.  I feel like I can use decorators, but no idea how.